How to set up Jasmine's report to print in the terminal inside an Angular project?
Is there a way to show Jasmine's report on my terminal instead of on the browser?
I know that there are some npm packages to print to console, but I couldn't set up to run inside my Angular 17 project.
In my terminal isn't printed the tests specs even if using ChromeHeadless.


